# jQuery image carrousel with fluid/liquid width

Tags: jquery, carousel, fluid, liquid-layout, fluid-layout

Does any of you know a jQuery image carrousel with fluid width?

I found this: http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/ ...but it look horrible when you set down the speed.

Further more, I would like it to be activated when the mouse moves in a direction, the slider should go the other way. What is that called, by the way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try carouFredSel: http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/intermediate-carousels.php
If you re-create the carousel onDocumentResize, it'll shrink to fit the available width, calculate the new number of visible items and center the items. It'll handle items with variable sizes too.

Comment: it has a responsive option now, so no need to work with onDocumentResize

Comment: I've found carouFredSel to be very useful and flexible, and implement it in a lot of projects. Here's the newer site for the plugin: http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel. The old documentation is also useful, as it links to an extensive variety of examples: http://docs.dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/

Answer (score 1):

Check this,
http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/

Answer (score 0):

I've personally been looking for the same thing. I was passed a link only yesterday to the following example by Ethan Marcotte (Responsive Web Design author/father), which is currently limited but it does handle fluid widths:
[Example](http://www.matmarquis.com/carousel/) / 
[Code download](https://github.com/Wilto/Dynamic-Carousel)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the new link for Kenneth B's answer is this: http://srosendal.dk/da/inspiration/ (sorry couldn't find the reply button to Jonathan Sampson)